# How to cut string at various signs

Tags: c++, string, getline

I´ve got the following problem:
I read in WinCC Variables from a .csv file. Now there is a string which contains the ip address. It looks like this: `I0043CTRL/CALH1$ST$Beh$stVal;Len=4;MMSType=133;Flag=RW`

The Address in this example is `I0043`.

Now I want to cut the string after the address, but there are more possible name of the variabel, for example `I0043PROT/...`.

Is there any possibility to tell for example getline to end at various signs?
Like: `getline(tmp_stringstream,tmp_string, 'C' || 'P');`

Thank you

Patrick

Comment: Boost has `boost::split`, which can do exactly what you want. As far as I know, the standard library does not have such a function, if you can't use boost, you will have to implement this yourself.

Comment: Is it always the first 5 characters? Also, [`std::string::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) will search a string until it finds any character matching specified characters.

Comment: @PeterWood No, unfortunately it`s not always like this, thats why I prefer the method from us2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::split` does what you need: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp163440592

```
std::string mystring("asd,ff.erw qewr");
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
boost::split( tokens, mystring, boost::is_any_of(",.-/ ") );
```

Comment: @Peter So? The OP was a new user, and just like the accepted answer on that meta thread says, I did ask politely. What exactly is it that you don't like about this?

Comment: @us2012 I didn't say I didn't like it. You were polite.

Answer (score 0):

In C runtime library there's a string tokenizer function, [strtok](http://www.elook.org/programming/c/strtok.html) (include < string.h>)

In C++ runtime there's an equivalent [std::strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) (include < cstring>)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::string::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of), and [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr):

```
string line("I0043CTRL/CALH1$ST$Beh$stVal;Len=4;MMSType=133;Flag=RW");

cout << line.substr(0, line.find_first_of("CP"));
```

output:

```
I0043
```

Comment: But then I again have the Problem when there is some other type of variable, they would be named "I0043PROT/..." for example. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you give a range of example inputs and outputs?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; I am doing exactly what you said in your question.

Comment: Ah, it`s my fault, I didn´t look up the find_first_of and thought it only works when all the signs are in the string.
I´ll try this version too, thank you.